Unable to edit .NET application startup file in Plesk
I got a problem that I cannot edit path of the .NET application startup file in Plesk although I logged in as administrator.
unable to edit application startup file
However, it seems like can be edited as on Plesk website.
https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/dotnet-application-hosting-in-plesk/
can be edited as on Plesk website
Can anyone suggest what might be going on?

It's up to the Plesk version to be allowed editing application startup file path on Plesk GUI or not.
In my case, specify application startup file path in web.config file by editing the arguments option:
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Application.Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />

